# How to access "view frame source" with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm loading an external domain site in an iFrame. I'm trying to monitor any url changes within that I frame and its location. I know there is a  restriction with 'Same Origin Policy'.  In chrome I can left click on an iFrame and select "view frame source" to view the html and other data.  Is there anyway to do this with javascript in conjunction with Chrome?

I tried to monitor the url through iframe.src however that property does not update on url change.

This is the iFrame I am using. Which I can view a change event via an onload function.

```
<iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porsche_911" frameborder="0" onload="monitor ">
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWaGNx?editors=1111

Comment: You can do that as the browser user, but code from a different domain cannot.

Comment: Assuming you must stick with JS and Chrome to do this, you can bypass those restrictions by creating a chrome browser extension

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless you have some kind of CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) arrangement with the source domain (they would need to white list your domain in the appropriate HTTP header).

CORS prevents access to the content of documents that come from another domain. This is for security reasons. Otherwise, what would prevent you from framing the secure login page of some bank, but modifying the code on it to send you the access details?